# (Google unit Testing) invalid use of void expression

Tags: c++

I'm attempting to run a unit test and keep getting this error. Is it not possible to test void functions with no return type? Also, I haven't passed in any arguments to my virtual void member functions so could that be it as well?

```
#ifndef __FACTORY_TEST_HPP__
#define __FACTORY_TEST_HPP__
#include "gtest/gtest.h"
#include "USN_Fleet_Factory.h"
#include "USN_Ship.h"
#include "GF_Class.h"
#include "T_Class.h"
#include "AB_Class.h"
#include "WH_Class.h"
#include <iostream>

TEST(FactoryTestSet, ShipNameTest) {
    USN_Fleet_Factory* makeAShip;
    USN_Ship *make;
    makeAShip = new USN_Ship_Factory;
    make = makeAShip->CreateAircraftCarrier("Aircraft Carrier");
    EXPECT_EQ(make->ShipName(), "- USS Gerald R. Ford");

}
#endif //__FACTORY_TEST_HPP__
```

Comment: Variables with `__` and `_[capital]` are reserved in C++, fyi. As for your question, how should the `void` function be tested? What do you wish for it to accomplish?

Comment: I want to test to see if make->ShipName() which should cout << "- USS Gerald R. Ford" is equal to "- USS Gerald R. Ford". https://ibb.co/tJ9wxNT @ChrisMM

Comment: Then no, you cannot test that. If the function returned the `string`, you could, but otherwise, not easily. It's possible to redirect `cout`, and examine the output.